# jquery bpopup.js - attaching bpopup to dynamic data

Tags: php, jquery, popup, bpopup

I have a website with a search function. The user enters his search parameters, and a popup (via bpopup.js) is displayed with links to the results.  I want the user to be able to click each link and have another iframe pop up with the data from that url. I plan to limit the user to 5 results at a time.  Currently my search works fine, and the popup comes up with the list of links.  However, when I click on each of the links, the data is loaded inside that particular iframe, not a new one. I want to be able to have multiple iframes open, which bpopup says is possible.

Here's the pertinent search.php code:

```
if($searcher->getResultCount() > 0) {
echo('<div><ul>');
    foreach($searcher->getResults() as $result) {
    $newclass="imagen" . $counter;
    $url = '<a id="' .  $newclass . '" href="' . $result['filePath'] . '">Test</a>';
    echo('<li><em>' . $url . '</em></li>');
    $counter++;
    }
echo('</ul></div>');
```

} else.....

At the bottom of search.php is where I set up my bpopup:

$(document).on(function() {

```
$(function() {
$('#searchResults').bPopup({
    content: 'iframe',
    contentContainer: '.searchResults',
    position: [200,200],
    follow: [false, false],
    opacity: 0,
    scrollBar: 'true'
});
$('#imagen1').bind('click', "a.imagen1",  function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var urltoLoad = $(this).attr("href");
            $('#result1').bPopup({
                content: 'iframe',
                contentContainer: '.resultcontent1',
                follow: [false, false],
                position: [50,200],
                positionStyle: 'fixed',
                closeClass: 'b-close1',
                scrollBar: 'true',
        escClose: 'true',
                loadUrl: urltoLoad
             });
         });....
```

There is one #imagen set up for each of the 5 results.

And finally,

```
 <div id = "searchResults"> </div> 
<div id = "result1">
<a class="b-close"></a>
<div class="resultcontent1"></div>
</div>
<div id = "result2">
<a class="b-close"></a>
<div class="resultcontent2"></div>
</div>
<div id = "result3">
<a class="b-close"></a>
<div class="resultcontent3"></div>
</div>
```